# Removing options from dropdown on form submit

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there any way I can use a dropdown list such that, if one user selects an option from the dropdown and submits the form, other users won't see that option at all (only have the other options to choose from)?

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to restrict choice options based on selections from other entries; however, this ability would be available with our upcoming Lookup Field feature:

https://trello.com/c/vKfb0oVP/132-lookup-field